# EditText not fully above Soft Keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

So I have been researching for like 2 hours on how to get this working: 
I need to have: `SwiperRefreshLayout -> ScrollView -> RelativeLayout -> EditText`

If the EditText contains 10 lines and I click on the 5th line, the keyboard does resize but only until the 5th line. I want it so that it resizes for the whole EditText. For example, if I click on the first line of the EditText, I want the whole 10 lines of it shown.

Things I have already tried:
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` 
Using RelativeLayout instead of Linear //

**XML: **

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
    android:id="@+id/swipe">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Open Saved Location"
                android:id="@+id/savedLocations"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Estimated Address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/savedLocations"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Unable to estimate address!"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/getAddress"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:autoText="false"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_below="@+id/getCords"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Unable to find latitude and longitude!"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/getCords"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save Location"
                android:id="@+id/saveLocation"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@+id/getAddress"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:maxLines="9"
                android:text="Unable to create message preview!"
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <Button
                android:text="Select Contact" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/selectContact"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@+id/message"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/saveLocation"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/saveLocation" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Message Preview"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/saveLocation"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.whereyouat" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MyCompatTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Contacts"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contacts"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MyCompatTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" >
            </meta-data>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TESTING"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_testing"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You can not solve it if you have everything in scrollview. If you could take your textview out of scrollview (if it is even possible for you) then you have a shot at solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to your manifest file

```
<activity
   android:name="com.android.test.LoginActivity"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying but I already tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @BaBazinga: Hey, I have updated my latest code to the above answer, I have tried into my project and its working fine.

Comment: Hey, have you checked my latest answer, hope it works for you.

Comment: Hey Parth, I just tried and still I have the same problem. I have just updated the question with the manifest. The MainActivity has a fragment called AddressFragment.

Comment: Ok. I got this, if you are using fragment and your fragment came from the activity , so for that activity you need to add this code to your manifest file, not to your fragment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93831/discussion-between-babazinga-and-parth-bhayani).

Comment: I did it just because I have a MainActivity in which I have three tabs, so I have added the above code to my MainActivity and that reflection came to your activity that was originally implemented in your project.